# MAUI Bind to model to show last element in a list

Tags: list, binding, maui

I am a bit stumped, please help.

I have a model like this:

```
public class ExpenseReport
{
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    etc
}
```

Now in my View I need to show the most recent comment for this ExpenseReport, and also show a "+" button which would show all the comments for this ExpenseReport in a new view.

How do I bind to the latest comment ?

What I have tried:

1. Have a hidden label like this and somehow read it in another Label control further down my xaml page:

but I don't think this could ever work.

2. In the code-behind of the view have some code in OnAppearing() which would read the ID of the ExpenseReport, query again the datasource for this specific ID, get the list of comments, and get the latest one and assign it to the text property of a named label in the view.
3. I have no idea on how to do this in the viewmodel at all.

Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 0):

create a read only property

```
public Comment MostRecentComment
{
   get {
     return Comments?.LastOrDefault();
   }
}
```